# Range("D14") is pasting twice, into D14 and D15.

Tags: vba, excel

For some reason this is being inserted into two cells when it should be only one.

Instead of it just pasting a value into D14, it also pastes the same value in D15.

My end goal here is to read an entire column and get all unique values within that column, minus the header, and get the speed.  So it may have 1 Gpbs, or 200 Mbps.  If it is 1 Gig, I want to strip off the 'gbps' and turn the 1 into 1000.  The data is basically a bunch of empty rows with an alphanumeric speed value. In this instance only one row value exists. so the data below is how it is in the sheet.

```
Dim Clb As Range
Dim lAnswer3 As Variant
With CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    For Each Clb In wbFrom.Sheets("Sheet0").Range("Z9", Range("Z" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))

        Clb.Value = Replace(Clb.Value, " Mbps", "")
        Clb.Value = Replace(Clb.Value, " Gbps", "")

       If Clb.Value = 1 Then
            Clb = Clb * 1000
        End If


        If Not .exists(Clb.Value) Then
        .Add Clb.Value, Nothing
        End If
    Next Clb

 lAnswer3 = wbFrom.Sheets("Sheet0").Evaluate("SUMPRODUCT(--z9:z50000)")

 wbTo.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D14").Resize(.Count).Value = lAnswer3  'D14 and D15 get populated

End With
```

Data:

```
NetSpeed
<blank row>
<blank row>
<blank row>
<blank row>
<blank row>
1 Gbps
<blank row>
<blank row>
```

Comment: Looks like `.Count` is worth `2` when you resize `Range("D14")`. While we're at it, why are you resizing `Range("D14")`?

Comment: To be honest I am not quiet sure -  I got the code sample from here and have tried to adapt it to my needs with limited success.  I just took that piece out and like magic it works as intended.  Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

The end solution, for me in this instance, was  cybernetic.nomad's comment.

I changed

```
wbTo.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D14").Resize(.Count).Value = lAnswer3  'D14 and D15 get populated
```

to

```
wbTo.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D14").Value = lAnswer3  'D14 and D15 get populated
```

and my duplication issue was resolved.